# Write Flex 3 code in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, apache-flex

Any ideas on how to build and compile flex 3 projects in visual studio?  I prefer that environment to Flex Builder 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tofino](http://www.ensemble.com/products/tofino.html)

It was just announced recently. Not sure how stable it is, but I'm almost positive it's going to be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

[Amethyst](http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Adobe-Flex-IDE-Amethyst-Beta-2) is another.  It's still in Beta, but it looks promising.